# How to make the js function "onClick" work only on the container div?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I got a problem with the onClick function. I have to set

```
display: none;
```

in a css container div when the user clicks on it, but not when he clicks on the divs which are in the container.

```
<div id="msg_background" onclick="javascript:closemsg();">
    <div id="new_msg_cont">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, i don't want that clicking on "new_msg_cont" the function still works.

Here's the js:

```
function closemsg() {
    document.getElementById('cont').style.height='';
    document.getElementById('cont').style.overflow='';
    document.getElementById('cont').style.position='';
    document.getElementById('msg_background').style.display='none';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (e.target === e.currentTarget) { this.display = "none"; }`. Would be better if you avoid inline event handlers, also `javascript:` prefix is useless in your case. Don't confuse `href` attribute with event attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but adding this to the function it doesn't work even clicking on the container div.

Comment: Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/Nz6r6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "bubbling" where the inner elements event 'bubbles' up to the parent element.

You can cancel this with `event.stopPropagation()`:

**Inline script**

```
<div onclick="event.stopPropagation();" id="new_msg_cont"></div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YE6fM/1/)

**External script**

```
div onclick="javascript:cancel(event);" id="new_msg_cont"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function cancel(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YE6fM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<div id="msg_background" onclick="javascript:closemsg(this);">
  <div id="new_msg_cont">
     ... your code ...    
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function closemsg(ele) {
  if(ele.id === 'msg_background'){
    document.getElementById('cont').style.height='';
    document.getElementById('cont').style.overflow='';
    document.getElementById('cont').style.position='';
    document.getElementById('msg_background').style.display='none';
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. The function works even clicking on the new_msg_cont div

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

javascript

```
function closemsg(event) {
    if(event.target.id == "msg_background" ){
        alert('you cliked me');
        document.getElementById('cont').style.height='';
        document.getElementById('cont').style.overflow='';
        document.getElementById('cont').style.position='';
        document.getElementById('msg_background').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

html

```
<div id="msg_background" onclick="closemsg(event);">
    div1
    <div id="new_msg_cont">
        div2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function check out if the event was fired by your parent div:

```
if (ev.target.id == "msg_background")
{
  //execute the contents of the closemsg function
}
```

(ev is the event parameter)

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kVuKA/1/